# Gráfico sem imagem jsp

Tags: jsp

Olá!
Estou querendo gerar gráfico pelo jsp

Tentei seguir [esse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Eg9gzbynRo&spfreload=5) tutorial

Mas só aparece um quadradinho no canto esquerdo da pagina quando executo
Arquivo `Torta.jsp`

```
<%  
    try{
      DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();    
      while(rs.next()){
          data.setValue(rs.getString("marca"), rs.getInt("TOTAL"));
      }

      JFreeChart grafico = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Cantidad Productos", data, true, true, true);

      response.setContentType("image/JPEG");
      OutputStream sa = response.getOutputStream();

      ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(sa, grafico, 600,600 );

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
%>
```

Arquivo `conexion.jsp`

```
<%
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/producto","root","123");
     Statement cmd= cn.createStatement();
     String sql = "SELECT MARCA, SUM(CANTIDAD) AS TOTAL FROM   PRODUCTO_CANTIDAD GROUP BY MARCA";
     ResultSet rs = cmd.executeQuery(sql);
%>
```

Imagem de como aparece o gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas possibilidades:

1. Como você está fazendo referência a essa imagem na página?
2. Você tentou executar essa query na base de dados pra ver se retorna dados?
3. Tentou colocar um ex.printStackTrace() no catch pra ver se não está ocorrendo algum erro na execução?

Comment: 1. Como você está fazendo referência a essa imagem na página?
Você tentou executar essa query na base de dados pra ver se retorna dados?
Tentou colocar um ex.printStackTrace() no catch pra ver se não está ocorrendo algum erro na execução?

Comment: 1Como você está fazendo referência a essa imagem na página?
    O Código só é esse

2. Você tentou executar essa query na base de dados pra ver se retorna dados?
    Sim. Retorna dados

3. Tentou colocar um ex.printStackTrace() no catch pra ver se não está ocorrendo algum erro na execução?
   Vou tentar agora

Comment: no console do chrome aparece assim:

net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Comment: Tente fechar o OutputStream ( sa.close() ), caso não funcione, chame o flush antes de fechar ( sa.flush() )... Parece ser porque o navegador não recebe o fim do arquivo...

Comment: Isso! Deu certo com sa.close();


Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Isso mesmo! Deu certíssimo! Era isso mesmo! Acrescentei o sa.close(); e funcionou. Muito obrigado!